# Jquery if input is empty add value and submit

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

I have had a hunt but can't get this to work. If an input on a form is empty, it needs to have a value added to it, and then be submitted, if it already has a value, then it is submitted with that value.

Code so far

```
    <form name="form1" action="http://csster.com/generate.php" method="post" id="formit">
Name: <input name="name" type="text" /><br/>
Mothers Name: <input id="desti" name="mname" type="text" /><br/>
Fathers Name: <input name="fname" type="text" /><br/>
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>


    $("#formit").submit(function(){
        if($("#desti:empty").text('Australia'));
});
```

[Check the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/webthread/65R9q/)

EDIT - Is it possible to make it so the added value is not visible before submitting, it may confuse people on the particular form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `val` method for form elements.

```
$("#formit").submit(function(){
    $("#desti").val(function(i, v){
        return $.trim(v) === '' ? 'Australia' : v;
    })
});
```

---

```
$("#formit").submit(function(){
    var $e = $("#desti");
    if ($e.val() === '') $e.val('Australia').addClass('aClass')
});
```

Comment: Please see my edit, is possible to make it not visible before submitting?

Comment: @Nik No, maybe you can hide the input, if you want to have a default value for the input, why no doing this on server-side?

Comment: I don't have access to the server, only client side :/ Could I just add a class to the input if it's empty that makes the text white?

Comment: @Nik Yes, you can change the color to white, or add a text-indent property.

Comment: that adds the class if it's not empty as well

Answer (score 5):

try this:

```
$("#formit").submit(function(){
     if ( $("#desti").val().length === 0 ) 
            $("#desti").val('Australia');
 });
```

Here is [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/65R9q/3/)

Comment: Cheers it always makes sense when you see it ;)

Answer (score 2):

you can get the input value with val() and set with val()

```
$("#formit").submit(function(){
    if($("#desti").val() === '')$("#desti").val('Oz')  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$("#formit").submit(function(){
```

`if ($('#desti').is(":empty")) {`

 `$('#desti').val('Australia');`
`}`
`});`